# Pausing AVPlayer on last second of playerItem

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, avplayer, nsnotificationcenter

Currently I have an AVPlayer controller that plays a specific video and loops it every time it reaches the end using

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(VideoPlayerController.playerItemDidReachEnd(_:)), name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: self.player?.currentItem)
```

and

```
func playerItemDidReachEnd(notification: NSNotification) {
    //code to restart player
}
```

I want to pause the player when it gets to a specific time in the video, for example one second before the end. How would I do this?

Is there a notification name like `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification` that is used in this instance for detecting when a certain time is reached?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for AVPlayer's `addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes:queue:usingBlock:`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval` to create a periodic event. In the event handler you can check the current time of the video, and pause if the time matches some criteria.

Example:

```
var player: AVPlayer!
var playerObserver: AnyObject!

func playVideo() {

    self.addPlayerPeriodicObserver()
    player.play()
}

func stopVideo() {

    removePlayerPeriodicObserver()
    player.pause()
}

func addPlayerPeriodicObserver() {

    removePlayerPeriodicObserver()

    // Time interval to check video playback.
    let interval = CMTime(seconds: 0.01, preferredTimescale: 1000)

    // Time limit to play up until.
    let duration = player.currentItem!.duration
    let limit = CMTime(seconds: 1.0, preferredTimescale: 1000)
    let maxTime = duration - limit

    // Schedule the event observer.
    playerObserver = player?.addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval(interval, queue: dispatch_get_main_queue()) { [unowned self] time in

        if self.player.currentTime() >= maxTime {

            // Time is at or past time limits - stop the video.
            self.stopVideo()
        }
    }
}

func removePlayerPeriodicObserver() {

    if let playerObserver = playerObserver {
        player?.removeTimeObserver(playerObserver)
    }

    playerObserver = nil
}
```

Comment: Yea of course. But mine is more versatile because you can apply more complex rules.

Comment: Both answers have been helpful but Luke's answer provided a working example which saves me some time. Thank you both!